# error AADSTS7000218 (@azure/msal-react, @azure/msal-browser) SPA whit React Js y Azure ad

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

Good morning , have you ever made the integration with Azure AD with an application made with REACT ??, and I followed the step by step of the Microsoft documentation (@ azure / msal-react and @ azure / msal-browser)
It seems that the authentication with email and password is carried out but when redirecting to the page, I receive an error AADSTS7000218 with the legend: "the body of the request must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'".
The problem is that I am not the Azure administrator and I already asked for some specific settings such as AllowPublicClients to true, but nothing else remains.

This is my configuration file:

```
import { LogLevel } from "@azure/msal-browser";
// Browser check variables
// If you support IE, our recommendation is that you sign-in using Redirect APIs
// If you as a developer are testing using Edge InPrivate mode, please add "isEdge" to the if check
const ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
const msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
const msie11 = ua.indexOf("Trident/");
const msedge = ua.indexOf("Edge/");
const firefox = ua.indexOf("Firefox");
const isIE = msie > 0 || msie11 > 0;
const isEdge = msedge > 0;
const isFirefox = firefox > 0; // Only needed if you need to support the redirect flow in Firefox incognito

// Config object to be passed to Msal on creation
export const msalConfig = {
  auth: {
    clientId: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_ID ,
    authority:
      `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${process.env.REACT_APP_TENANT_ID}`,
    redirectUri: process.env.REACT_APP_HOST,
    clientSecret: process.env.REACT_APP_CLIENT_SECRET,
  },
  cache: {
    storeAuthStateInCookie: isIE || isEdge || isFirefox,
  },
  system: {
    loggerOptions: {
      loggerCallback: (level, message, containsPii) => {
        if (containsPii) {
          return;
        }
        switch (level) {
          case LogLevel.Error:
            console.error(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Info:
            console.info(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Verbose:
            console.debug(message);
            return;
          case LogLevel.Warning:
            console.warn(message);
            return;
          default:
            return;
        }
      },
    },
  },
};

// Add here scopes for id token to be used at MS Identity Platform endpoints.
export const loginRequest = {
  scopes: ["profile"],
};

// Add here the endpoints for MS Graph API services you would like to use.
export const graphConfig = {
  graphMeEndpoint: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me",
};
```